# Silencing errors in Grape/Goliath

Tags: ruby, error-handling, ruby-grape, goliath

I'm working with a Grape API running on Goliath. Currently, if a method returns an error for some reason, the client receives a 500 – *and the exact error raised*!

How can I silence the output from the API and just have it return a generic 500 error?

Comment: https://github.com/intridea/grape#default-error-http-status-code

Comment: @mudasobwa – is that just for changing the default HTTP error code, rather than the message that comes back to the client?

Comment: The issue is raised here: https://github.com/postrank-labs/goliath/issues/50, but I still don't see how I can catch the errors. Did you manage to find a solution?